# How to make the TableView scrollable with already loaded data in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am able to fetch list of data from a restful web service. The goal is to display the same in the form of rows in iPhone application.

I could able to bring up the table with data while rendering the view. But I could not able to scroll down to see all the result.

Do I need to implement any method in the View Controller?

Also I am able to add detail disclosure button for each row. For touchdown action on the disclosure button, which method do i need to implement in View Controller?

Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton

Please suggest.

EDITED :

Here is the code snippet how am adding UI button in a row:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are loading the data from a web service synchronously, so the UI thread will be blocked until it is done, and you will not be able to scroll the table view. Use `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation`, GCD, `NSURLConnection` and a delegate, or a library like AFNetworking to load data asynchronously.

As for the disclosure button, see [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for `UITableViewDelegate`. Specifically, you are interested in `-tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`.

Comment: I did implement that method (accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath) in my controller, but on click control is not coming to that method while debuting. Any clue what am missing here? Do we need to pass any id to id while adding button?

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:*arrayOfIndexPaths* withRowAnimation:*rowAnimation*];
[tableView endUpdates];
```